# How to round up a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to round up the values of column in pandas. I need to round up the values of column.

```
     hostname    ip           date      cpu  cpumax  
0    mysql      192.168.1.1  22-Aug-19  12.0   10.33   
1    cassandra  192.168.2.1  22-Aug-19   2.0   92.43
```

My Code is below which is working fine.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import math
 data_file['cpumax'] = np.ceil((data_file['cpumax'])+0.5)
```

My cpumax column is

```
cpumax
11
93
```

Is there any alternative like `math.ceil`. Since math.ceil I can't apply here  since its not Series

Comment: Why don't you want to use `np.ceil`?  Your code works just fine.

Comment: Why do you add `0.5` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

np.ceil should do it but if you still want to use math.ceil use

`df['cpumax'] = df['cpumax'].apply(math.ceil)`

Answer (score 2):

Import numpy as np

```
df['cpumax'] = np.ceil(df['cpumax']).astype(int)
```